# I have one input having three different values. How can i scan three values form a single scanner

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

> Next t lines contain three space-separated integers N, B1, B2 and
> where N is the number of sides in the polygon and B1, B2 denote the
> vertices that are colored black.

How can I extract numbers from single input using only one scanner object?

Comment: Read whole line as a string - then parse the string to extract your 3 integers, you can also use 'str.split(" ")' to split space separated values

Comment: Or just the same way you've done before: nextInt() for each integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ")` which will return a String array of the values that are entered on a single line. For example, if `1 2 3` is entered from the console, in `input` you will have `["1", "2", "3"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Scanner`, a simple `Scanner.nextInt()` will suffice to read integers as long as they are separated by whitespace as mentioned in your problem statement.

> [*A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

For instance:

```
int n1,n2;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
n1=sc.nextInt();
n2=sc.nextInt();
```

If the input is `20 40`,
n1 will store 20 and n2 will store 40.

See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--